# Git Reverting a commit post a merge

Tags: git, git-commit, git-revert

I have the following situation:

```
Remote: A<-B<-----C<-D<-------\
Local:      \-B1<------B2<-B3<-M
```

So, I have merged a pull from the remote into my local repo (M). I now want to revert B3 and go back to B2.
I tried doing a

```
git revert --no-commit -m 1 M
git revert --continue
```

Now my git log shows the following:

```
commit R
Revert "Merge branch 'master' of https://...."
This reverts commit M, reversing changes made to B3

commit M
....

commit B3
....

....
```

However, even though the git log mentions "*reversing changes made to B3*", when I do a git status, it shows the same things I expect *after* B3 commit.
Also it appears, I actually went forward rather than backward (new commit R).

My Questions:

1. How do I get back to B2?
2. Was reverting the merge the right thing to do/required?

Comment: git reset, git merge?

Comment: Or maybe git checkout?

Answer (score 0):

You can reset `master` back to `B2` and do the merge:

```
git reset --hard B2
git merge remote/master
```

Commits are immutable, so if you want to merge into a different commit, you have to do it from scratch.

On the other hand, if you are happy with your history and want to just look at `B2`, you can check it out:

```
git checkout B2
```

Most likely `revert` is not what you are looking for. `revert` will add a set of commits that invert the changes introduced by the range you selected. There are usually simpler ways of getting to the state you want.